# USB Audio and Video devices no longer work after Windows 10 Update KB3176493

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, audio, drivers

I'm not sure if it's related to KB3176493 as I can't find anything else relating. I've been searching all day and all I've found are a ton of totally unrelated Windows XP/8 posts. Anyway, came to my Computer today to find it rebooted. Great, update with telling me. Then I notice none of my devices work! Networking, Bluetooth, USB Audio, USB Video ... all gone! They've got the little yellow exclamation marks int he device manager.

[image: Device manager missing devices]

I download the network/wireless drivers and reinstall those; they work fine. However none of my USB audio/video devices work and I cannot get them working. These are system devices after all; drivers should be included with Windows. However I keep getting this error:

[image: error in driver search dialog]

I check my `C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log` to see the following:

```
>>>  [Device Install (DiShowUpdateDevice) - USB\VID_262A&PID_1100&MI_01\6&1BFC5E0F&0&0001]
>>>  Section start 2016/08/17 12:58:57.120
      cmd: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmc.exe" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\compmgmt.msc" /s
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI} 12:58:57.125
     dvi:      Default installer: Enter 12:58:57.130
     dvi:      Default installer: Exit
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI - exit(0xe000020e)} 12:58:57.155
     ndv: {Update Driver Software Wizard for USB\VID_262A&PID_1100&MI_01\6&1BFC5E0F&0&0001}
     sto:      {Setup Import Driver Package: c:\windows\inf\wdma_usb.inf} 12:59:05.531
!    sto:           Unable to determine presence of driver package. Error = 0x00000002
     inf:           Provider: Microsoft
     inf:           Class GUID: {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
     inf:           Driver Version: 10/29/2015,10.0.10586.0
     sto:           {Copy Driver Package: c:\windows\inf\wdma_usb.inf} 12:59:05.592
     sto:                Driver Package = c:\windows\inf\wdma_usb.inf
     sto:                Flags          = 0x00000007
     sto:                Destination    = C:\Users\cassius\AppData\Local\Temp\{43ca80c4-fc5c-4443-a1ed-a1fba89dbae7}
     sto:                Copying driver package files to 'C:\Users\cassius\AppData\Local\Temp\{43ca80c4-fc5c-4443-a1ed-a1fba89dbae7}'.
     flq:                Copying 'c:\windows\inf\wdma_usb.inf' to 'C:\Users\cassius\AppData\Local\Temp\{43ca80c4-fc5c-4443-a1ed-a1fba89dbae7}\wdma_usb.inf'.
!!!  flq:                Error installing file (0x00000002)
!!!  flq:                Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
!    flq:                     SourceFile   - 'c:\windows\inf\USBAUDIO.sys'
!    flq:                     TargetFile   - 'C:\Users\cassius\AppData\Local\Temp\{43ca80c4-fc5c-4443-a1ed-a1fba89dbae7}\USBAUDIO.sys'
!!!  cpy:                Failed to copy file 'c:\windows\inf\USBAUDIO.sys' to 'C:\Users\cassius\AppData\Local\Temp\{43ca80c4-fc5c-4443-a1ed-a1fba89dbae7}\USBAUDIO.sys'. Error = 0x00000002
!!!  flq:                SPFQNOTIFY_COPYERROR: returned SPFQOPERATION_ABORT.
!!!  flq:                Error 995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
!!!  flq:                FileQueueCommit aborting!
!!!  flq:                Error 995: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
!!!  sto:                Failed to copy driver package to 'C:\Users\cassius\AppData\Local\Temp\{43ca80c4-fc5c-4443-a1ed-a1fba89dbae7}'. Error = 0x00000002
     sto:           {Copy Driver Package: exit(0x00000002)} 12:59:05.839
     sto:      {Setup Import Driver Package - exit (0x00000002)} 12:59:05.848
!!!  ndv:      Driver package import failed for device.
!!!  ndv:      Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
     ndv:      Installing NULL driver.
     dvi:      {Plug and Play Service: Device Install for USB\VID_262A&PID_1100&MI_01\6&1BFC5E0F&0&0001}
!    ndv:           Installing NULL driver!
     dvi:           {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL} 12:59:06.377
     dvi:                Default installer: Enter 12:59:06.380
     dvi:                Default installer: Exit
     dvi:           {DIF_ALLOW_INSTALL - exit(0xe000020e)} 12:59:06.395
     dvi:           {DIF_REGISTER_COINSTALLERS} 12:59:06.403
     dvi:                Default installer: Enter 12:59:06.406
     dvi:                Default installer: Exit
     dvi:           {DIF_REGISTER_COINSTALLERS - exit(0x00000000)} 12:59:06.411
     dvi:           {DIF_INSTALLDEVICE} 12:59:06.413
     dvi:                Default installer: Enter 12:59:06.422
!    dvi:                     Installing NULL driver!
     dvi:                     Install Null Driver: Removing device sub-tree. 12:59:06.439
     dvi:                     Install Null Driver: Removing device sub-tree completed. 12:59:06.446
     dvi:                     Install Null Driver: Restarting device. 12:59:06.470
     dvi:                     Install Null Driver: Restarting device completed. 12:59:06.477
     dvi:                     Install Device: Starting device. 12:59:06.492
     dvi:                     Install Device: Starting device completed. 12:59:06.525
     dvi:                Default installer: Exit
     dvi:           {DIF_INSTALLDEVICE - exit(0x00000000)} 12:59:06.530
     ump:      {Plug and Play Service: Device Install exit(00000000)}
<ins>
ᠻܗƲ$6 L66    ᡟN×$6 餶
```

This file doesn't exist. I installed a fresh Windows 10 VM to grab it and ... it doesn't exist on a new install! There is a file called USBAUDIO.sys in the `System32\Drivers` directory, but if I try copying that to this location, I get another error about unsigned INF files!

I've searched and searched and cannot find a solution to this. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered a solution. The **TL;DR** is that I downloaded and installed **Windows10Upgrade28084.exe** from Microsoft's website.

The full write up of how I diagnosed this issue can be found here:

http://penguindreams.org/blog/windows-10-update-kb3176493-all-my-drivers-disappeared/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error **"The system cannot find the file specified"** with USB audio and MTP storage, but instead of 28084 (which simply indicated that my system is up to date), the Windows10Upgrade**9252**.exe helped.

Comment: Assuming that 9252 is almost 20.000 versions older than the most recent update of Windows 10, this sounds like a very bad solution security-wise.

Comment: The weird thing is that 9252 did update me to [1803](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1803), which is from this July (and supposedly was already installed). It seems that both of those files are supposed to download the latest update file, but 28084 didn't detect whatever problem there was with previous updates.

Comment: I really don't know how windows update versioning works, so I'm sorry if it's actually not *that* old. But in general it's good practice to stay as updated as possible. But I understand that microsoft can't handle every single bug-report in quick time so a downgrade might be the only workaround.